# Using Trebuchet MS font

Tags: fonts

Is it possible to get this font in LaTeX?
I found a way by using XeLaTeX, however, I'm working on LaTeX => PS => PDF.

Comment: What you can do with LaTeX you can with XeLaTeX, as far as I know.

Comment: I want the font to work in my profile LaTeX => PS => PDF not in XeLaTeX.

Comment: You have the `winfonts` package, available on [CTAN](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/fonts/), but you'll have to install it by yourself: it is not part of any distribution, probably for licensing reasons.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is XeLaTeX out of the question?

Comment: I can't get it to work. I don't understand step 2 in the file ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/fonts/winfonts/README Can you help please?

Comment: @Bernard Note the package description says `...there is no pro­vi­sion for cre­at­ing PostScript files that use the fonts.` Hence I don't think this package can support the compilation method the OP is using? Or have I misunderstood something here about how Windows works? (Or, rather, is there something about how Windows works which would be relevant? I can't have misunderstood something about which I am completely and utterly ignorant. Hopefully.)

Comment: I have this font set up for use with pdfTeX (but not with TeX as I'm not even sure whether the licence would permit converting the font). And I guess the same goes for the `winfonts` package. So it can be done for pdfTeX, at least. *If* the licence permits it, it can be done for TeX, too, to support the generation of postscript. But the font licence may not permit converting the fonts. (Which might even be why `winfonts` doesn't do it that way.)

Comment: @cfr: You're probably right. I was stuck on not using XeLaTeX, anf forgot LaTeX can't use TrueType fonts.

Comment: I'm bringing up this because now I'm using WinEdt and I wonder if I can use this font on LaTeX.